# C# Xamarin Can't find activity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class, xamarin, android-activity

I am struggling with a problem.

This is my code:

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.CoinInfo);
var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(CoinInfoAdapter));
intent.PutExtra("SelectedCoinName", mItems[e.Position].CoinName);
intent.PutExtra("PositionToUse", e.Position);
StartActivity(intent);
```

I get an error on the last line:

```
StartActivity(intent);
```

The error is: "Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException:

But I created a class called: ProductInfo.cs.
And the Class includes:

```
class ProductInfo : Activity
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `ProductInfo` public and does it have an `ActivityAttribute` on it?

Comment: Just take a look at your code. You're making an intent from `CoinInfoAdapter` which seems to be an adapter not your `ProductInfo` activity.